# Calculate image variance in Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

How can I calculate the variation of an image in Imagick? I already converted the image in greyscale, but through native functions I can only get Mean and Standard Deviation.

Comment: What do you mean with `variation`?

Comment: It's a metric that goes along standard deviation and mean

Comment: Doing a bit of research I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6CxU_ftVTY). So it should be no big problem creating a third image of the difference as you can read out the pixel data.

Comment: can you provide any examples of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain more information, like the code you are currently using and an explanation about what is missing

Answer (score 0):

My approach is generating two noise images and calculate the Euclidian difference between both RGB pixel color values.

This will certainly look better with real images for example of a webcam.

[image: Noise and Difference]

```
$getRandomNoiseImage = function ($x, $y, $steps): Imagick {
    $draw = new ImagickDraw();
    $draw->setResolution($x, $y);
    $draw->setStrokeWidth(1);
    $pixel = new ImagickPixel();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $i += $steps) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < $y; $j += $steps) {
            $color = join(',', [rand(0, 255), rand(0, 255), rand(0, 255)]);
            $pixel->setColor("rgb($color)");
            $draw->setFillColor($pixel);
            $draw->setStrokeColor($pixel);
            $draw->rectangle($i, $j, $i + $steps, $j + $steps);
        }
    }
    $im = new Imagick();
    $im->newImage($x, $y, new ImagickPixel('black'));
    $im->drawImage($draw);

    return $im;
};

$width  = 64;
$height = 64;
$im1    = $getRandomNoiseImage($width, $height, 16);
$im2    = $getRandomNoiseImage($width, $height, 16);

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setResolution($width, $height);
$draw->setStrokeWidth(1);
$pixel = new ImagickPixel();

for ($i = 0; $i < $width; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $height; $j++) {
        $c1    = $im1->getImagePixelColor($i, $j)->getColor(0);
        $c2    = $im2->getImagePixelColor($i, $j)->getColor(0);
        $color = [
          sqrt(abs($c2['r']**2 - $c1['r']**2)),
          sqrt(abs($c2['g']**2 - $c1['g']**2)),
          sqrt(abs($c2['b']**2 - $c1['b']**2)),
        ];
        $pixel->setColor(sprintf('rgb(%d,%d,%d)', ...$color));
        $draw->setFillColor($pixel);
        $draw->setStrokeColor($pixel);
        $draw->rectangle($i, $j, $i + 1, $j + 1);
    }
}

$im3 = new Imagick();
$im3->newImage($width, $height, new ImagickPixel('black'));
$im3->drawImage($draw);

$im1->writeImage('image1.png');
$im2->writeImage('image2.png');
$im3->writeImage('image3.png');
```